# How to run phantomJS without nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, testing, phantomjs, web-testing

I have to UI test an application on a clients environment, where I cannot install new software and hence have no node.js. Furthermore, the only browser I have is IE 9.

Under these circumstances I would like to use PhantomJS to test my webapp. How can I run it without node.js?

Comment: If you cannot install new software, doesn't that rule out phantomjs too or do you *already* have that installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS can be installed through npm (node package manager), but it isn't a node module and cannot be used directly as such. You don't have to install it through npm. Just [download](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) the exe (I assume you are on windows since you're using IE9) and run it from a command prompt. If you cannot do this, then you're out of luck of using PhantomJS on your system.

All other testing frameworks also need to be installed in some way. For example, for using selenium with iedriver, you would need to install language and language bindings of your choice.